# GitLab Integration - Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, phpunit, gitlab-ci

[image]

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done

but sonar is showing 0% code coverage

Comment: What do you have for `sonar.tests` and `sonar.sources`?  Please post all the relevant lines of code here, not a screenshot

Comment: Only generating a code coverage report does not magically make it appear in Sonar. You need to configure it according to their docs and check the analysis log, it normally shows you errors, e.g. not finding the file, not finding the files that should be covered etc. pp.